# Realtime data from mysql database

Tags: highcharts, real-time-updates

my aim is to have a realtime graph or a dynamic using Highchart library.But i am not able to create a realtime chart what i have been doing is refreshing the page .Can someone please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will have a better experience here if you take the  [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question with the details needed to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Have you already checked this demo from the official Highcharts demo base? It should help you to create your own live chart. https://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update